# Problema ao adicionar o spinner no meu formulario

Tags: android, android-layout, spinners

Estou desenvolvendo um formulário onde quero adicionar o spinner, porem quando adiciono ele no arquivo xml, não aparece nada na tela, somente a caixa marcada como vocês podem ver abaixo:[image: erro]

Já adicionei as opções do meu spinner em STRINGS. Aqui esta meu arquivo xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/nome1"
        android:textColorHint="#9b9a9a"
        android:hint="*Nome:"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textColorLink="#050000"
        android:backgroundTint="#020000"
        android:textColor="#050000"
        android:layout_above="@+id/email"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/msg"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/msg"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/msg" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="#9b9a9a"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:hint="*E-mail:"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textColorLink="#050000"
        android:backgroundTint="#020000"
        android:textColor="#050000"
        android:layout_above="@+id/msg"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/msg"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/msg"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/msg"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/msg" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="#9b9a9a"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/telefone"
        android:hint="Telefone:"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textColorLink="#050000"
        android:backgroundTint="#020000"
        android:textColor="#050000"
        android:layout_above="@+id/nome1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/msg"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/msg"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/msg" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Enviar"
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView8" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="#9b9a9a"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/endereco"
        android:hint="Endereço:"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textColorLink="#050000"
        android:backgroundTint="#020000"
        android:textColor="#050000"
        android:layout_above="@+id/telefone"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/msg"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/msg"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/msg" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="5"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/msg"
        android:hint="*Mensagem"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textColorHint="#9b9a9a"
        android:layout_above="@+id/send"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/send"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/send"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView8"
        android:backgroundTint="#020000"
        android:textColor="#050000"
        android:textColorLink="#050000" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/endereco"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/endereco"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

E aqui está a minha classe onde é chamado a intent do formulário:

```
public class Reclame extends Cronograma implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

    Spinner opcoes;
    Button btnSend;
    EditText Nome;
    String Subject;
    EditText Message;
    EditText Endereco;
    EditText Telefone;
    EditText Email;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reclame, container, false);



        Nome = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.nome1);
        Subject = "Reclamação";
        Message = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.msg);
        Endereco = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.endereco);
        Telefone = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.telefone);
        Email = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.email);
        btnSend = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.send);
        opcoes = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        opcoes.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(v.getContext(), R.array.option, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                opcoes.setAdapter(adapter);


                String nome = Nome.getText().toString();
                String message = Message.getText().toString();
                String matricula = Endereco.getText().toString();
                String telefone = Telefone.getText().toString();
                String ema = Email.getText().toString();
                Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"meu_email"});
                email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, Subject);
                email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Nome: " +nome +'\n'+  "Endereço: "+matricula + '\n'+ "Telefone: "+telefone + '\n'+ "E-mail: "+ema + '\n'+ '\n'+message);


                email.setType("message/rfc822");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Selecione o serviço de e-mail:"));
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView mtext = (TextView) view;
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Você selecionou: "+mtext.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

O que estou fazendo de errado, que nao aparece o spinner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passe o código que inicializa o Adapter do spinner para dentro do `onCreateView()`

Antes obtenha uma referência a um Context para usar em `ArrayAdapter.createFromResource()`:

```
private Context contex;
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {

    context = activity; //Guarda context.

    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reclame, container, false);

    ......
    opcoes = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.option, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    opcoes.setAdapter(adapter);

    opcoes.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    .......
}
```

Comment: Fiz o que sugeriu  e apareceu, só que mesmo assim nao aparece o spinner. o que acho estranho é que quando adiciono ele no xml ele nao mostra a caixa ITEM 1, apenas mostra a caixa como você ver na primeira imagem.

Comment: O *array* `option` tem elementos?

Comment: ramaral eu consegui resolver o problema, ele esta adicionando o spinner no formulário, o pró é que o spinner ta invisível, só achei pq quando sai clicando na tela desceu as opções do spinner, porem quando escolho uma opção ele volta a ficar invisivel

Comment: No *spinner* tem `android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"` no entanto não vejo nenhum *imageView*

Comment: Eu retirei essa linha.. e mudei o meu tema e ja apareceu as opçoes, porem quando escolho a opçao, volta a sumir.